# A small linear algebra doubt

Tags: linear-algebra

In a proof i was reading today had this part which i cannot prove.
Given,

1. $S$ is a subset of vector space $V$
2. $A$ is a subset of $S$
3. $S$ is a subset of $\text{span}(A)$
4. Every element of $S$ can be expressed uniquely by elements of $A$

**Prove: A is linearly independent**

Comment: What is your "small doubt" ?

Comment: I'm sorry i wasn't clear. The question I've posted is part of a proof. So this 'small' part is the 'doubt'

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $A:\ \{a_i\}$ is linearly dependent: $\sum\limits_i c_ia_i=0$ for $\sum\limits_i |c_i|\ne 0$ then we take $a\in S$.
By (4) $\sum\limits_i b_ia_i=a$, but $\sum\limits_i (b_i+c_i)a_i=a$ too, and $\{b_i\}$ are different from $\{b_i+c_i\}$ because not all $c_i=0$, hence a contradiction with (4) uniqueness, QED.

Comment: Wow. This is amazing. thanks a lot